# Add Header and Footer in the PDF created by using AlivePDF

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, pdf-generation, datatables, alivepdf

I am using jQuery DataTables plugins to create HTML tables and using the DataTables TableTools to generate the PDF of my Table data. It is working fine now I want to add the header and footer in the generated PDF. PDF generation code is written in ActonScript3 file using AlivePDF. So any one can help me on this how can I add header and footer code in my ActionScript3 file that usages AlivePDF. Below is the code :

```
package {

    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.system.Security;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.system.System;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;

    /* PDF imports */
    import org.alivepdf.pdf.PDF;
    import org.alivepdf.data.Grid;
    import org.alivepdf.data.GridColumn;
    import org.alivepdf.layout.Orientation;
    import org.alivepdf.layout.Size;
    import org.alivepdf.layout.Unit;
    import org.alivepdf.display.Display;
    import org.alivepdf.saving.Method;
    import org.alivepdf.fonts.FontFamily;
    import org.alivepdf.fonts.Style;
    import org.alivepdf.fonts.CoreFont;
    import org.alivepdf.colors.RGBColor;

    public class ZeroClipboard extends Sprite {

        private var domId:String = '';
        private var button:Sprite;
        private var clipText:String = 'blank';
        private var fileName:String = '';
        private var action:String = 'copy';
        private var incBom:Boolean = true;
        private var charSet:String = 'utf8';


        public function ZeroClipboard() {
            // constructor, setup event listeners and external interfaces
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
            flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*");

            // import flashvars
            var flashvars:Object = LoaderInfo( this.root.loaderInfo ).parameters;
            domId = flashvars.id.split("\\").join("\\\\");

            // Validate id to prevent scripting attacks. The id given is an integer
            if ( domId !== parseInt( domId, 10 ).toString() ) {
                throw new Error( 'Invalid DOM id' );
            }

            // invisible button covers entire stage
            button = new Sprite();
            button.buttonMode = true;
            button.useHandCursor = true;
            button.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
            button.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
            button.alpha = 0.0;
            addChild(button);

            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:Event):void {
                clickHandler(event);
            } );
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(event:Event):void {
                ExternalInterface.call( 'ZeroClipboard_TableTools.dispatch', domId, 'mouseOver', null );
            } );
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, function(event:Event):void {
                ExternalInterface.call( 'ZeroClipboard_TableTools.dispatch', domId, 'mouseOut', null );
            } );
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(event:Event):void {
                ExternalInterface.call( 'ZeroClipboard_TableTools.dispatch', domId, 'mouseDown', null );
            } );
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(event:Event):void {
                ExternalInterface.call( 'ZeroClipboard_TableTools.dispatch', domId, 'mouseUp', null );
            } );

            // External functions - readd whenever the stage is made active for IE
            addCallbacks();
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, addCallbacks);

            // signal to the browser that we are ready
            ExternalInterface.call( 'ZeroClipboard_TableTools.dispatch', domId, 'load', null );
        }

        public function addCallbacks (evt:Event = null):void {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("setHandCursor", setHandCursor);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("clearText", clearText);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("setText", setText);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("appendText", appendText);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("setFileName", setFileName);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("setAction", setAction);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("setCharSet", setCharSet);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("setBomInc", setBomInc);
        }


        public function setCharSet(newCharSet:String):void {
            if ( newCharSet == 'UTF16LE' ) {
                charSet = newCharSet;
            } else {
                charSet = 'UTF8';
            }
        }

        public function setBomInc(newBomInc:Boolean):void {
            incBom = newBomInc;
        }

        public function clearText():void {
            clipText = '';
        }

        public function appendText(newText:String):void {
            clipText += newText;
        }

        public function setText(newText:String):void {
            clipText = newText;
        }

        public function setFileName(newFileName:String):void {
            fileName = newFileName;
        }

        public function setAction(newAction:String):void {
            action = newAction;
        }

        public function setHandCursor(enabled:Boolean):void {
            // control whether the hand cursor is shown on rollover (true)
            // or the default arrow cursor (false)
            button.useHandCursor = enabled;
        }


        private function clickHandler(event:Event):void {
            var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, saveComplete);

            if ( action == "save" ) {
                /* Save as a file */
                if ( charSet == 'UTF16LE' ) {
                    fileRef.save( strToUTF16LE(clipText), fileName );
                } else {
                    fileRef.save( strToUTF8(clipText), fileName );
                }
            } else if ( action == "pdf" ) {
                /* Save as a PDF */
                var pdf:PDF = configPdf();
                fileRef.save( pdf.save( Method.LOCAL ), fileName );
            } else {
                /* Copy the text to the clipboard. Note charset and BOM have no effect here */
                System.setClipboard( clipText );
                ExternalInterface.call( 'ZeroClipboard_TableTools.dispatch', domId, 'complete', clipText );
            }
        }


        private function saveComplete(event:Event):void {
            ExternalInterface.call( 'ZeroClipboard_TableTools.dispatch', domId, 'complete', clipText );
        }


        private function getProp( prop:String, opts:Array ):String
        {
            var i:int, iLen:int;
            for ( i=0, iLen=opts.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
            {
                if ( opts[i].indexOf( prop+":" ) != -1 )
                {
                    return opts[i].replace( prop+":", "" );
                }
            }
            return "";
        }


        private function configPdf():PDF
        {
            var
                pdf:PDF,
                i:int, iLen:int,
                splitText:Array    = clipText.split("--/TableToolsOpts--\n"),
                opts:Array         = splitText[0].split("\n"),
                dataIn:Array       = splitText[1].split("\n"),
                aColRatio:Array    = getProp( 'colWidth', opts ).split('\t'),
                title:String       = getProp( 'title', opts ),
                message:String     = getProp( 'message', opts ),
                orientation:String = getProp( 'orientation', opts ),
                size:String        = getProp( 'size', opts ),
                iPageWidth:int     = 0,
                dataOut:Array      = [],
                columns:Array      = [],
                headers:Array,
                y:int = 0;

            /* Create the PDF */
            pdf = new PDF( Orientation[orientation.toUpperCase()], Unit.MM, Size[size.toUpperCase()] );
            pdf.setDisplayMode( Display.FULL_WIDTH );
            pdf.addPage();
            iPageWidth = pdf.getCurrentPage().w-20;
            pdf.textStyle( new RGBColor(0), 1 );

            /* Add the title / message if there is one */
            pdf.setFont( new CoreFont(FontFamily.HELVETICA), 14 );
            if ( title != "" )
            {
                pdf.writeText(11, title+"\n");
            }

            pdf.setFont( new CoreFont(FontFamily.HELVETICA), 11 );
            if ( message != "" )
            {
                pdf.writeText(11, message+"\n");
            }

            /* Data setup. Split up the headers, and then construct the columns */
            for ( i=0, iLen=dataIn.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
            {
                if ( dataIn[i] != "" )
                {
                    dataOut.push( dataIn[i].split("\t") );
                }
            }
            headers = dataOut.shift();

            for ( i=0, iLen=headers.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
            {
                columns.push( new GridColumn( " \n"+headers[i]+"\n ", i.toString(), aColRatio[i]*iPageWidth, 'C' ) );
            }

            var grid:Grid = new Grid(
                dataOut,                  /* 1. data */
                iPageWidth,               /* 2. width */
                100,                      /* 3. height */
                new RGBColor (0xE0E0E0),  /* 4. headerColor */
                new RGBColor (0xFFFFFF),  /* 5. backgroundColor */
                true,                     /* 6. alternateRowColor */
                new RGBColor ( 0x0 ),     /* 7. borderColor */
                .1,                       /* 8. border alpha */
                null,                     /* 9. joins */
                columns                   /* 10. columns */
            );

            pdf.addGrid( grid, 0, y );
            return pdf;
        }


        /*
         * Function: strToUTF8
         * Purpose:  Convert a string to the output utf-8
         * Returns:  ByteArray
         * Inputs:   String
         */
        private function strToUTF8( str:String ):ByteArray {
            var utf8:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

            /* BOM first */
            if ( incBom ) {
                utf8.writeByte( 0xEF );
                utf8.writeByte( 0xBB );
                utf8.writeByte( 0xBF );
            }
            utf8.writeUTFBytes( str );

            return utf8;
        }


        /*
         * Function: strToUTF16LE
         * Purpose:  Convert a string to the output utf-16
         * Returns:  ByteArray
         * Inputs:   String
         * Notes:    The fact that this function is needed is a little annoying. Basically, strings in
         *   AS3 are UTF-16 (with surrogate pairs and everything), but characters which take up less
         *   than 8 bytes appear to be stored as only 8 bytes. This function effective adds the 
         *   padding required, and the BOM
         */
        private function strToUTF16LE( str:String ):ByteArray {
            var utf16:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var iChar:uint;
            var i:uint=0, iLen:uint = str.length;

            /* BOM first */
            if ( incBom ) {
                utf16.writeByte( 0xFF );
                utf16.writeByte( 0xFE );
            }

            while ( i < iLen ) {
                iChar = str.charCodeAt(i);

                if ( iChar < 0xFF ) {
                    /* one byte char */
                    utf16.writeByte( iChar );
                    utf16.writeByte( 0 );
                } else {
                    /* two byte char */
                    utf16.writeByte( iChar & 0x00FF );
                    utf16.writeByte( iChar >> 8 );
                }

                i++;
            }

            return utf16;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hack the Actionscript to add an image, for example, as a header and a footer, you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222352/actionscript-3-0-load-an-image-programatically)

It will be probably the easiest way if you don't know Actionscript

Comment: Thanks @Harrison, I have done this with different way. I used image as base64 to add in PDF.